# use row value for selecting column in mysqli

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in mysqli:

```
table a:
cluster, id, number
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
c_a   1   135
c_a   2   155
c_a   3   187
c_b   1   232
c_b   2   984
c_b   3   213

table b:
user, c_a, c_b
_ _ _ _ _ _
alex 1  2
lia  3  1
```

I want to get the rows of table a where the cluster and the id correspond to the entry in table b for a specific user. E.g. Alex has id=1 in cluster a and id=2 in cluster b, so for alex I want the output:

```
c_a   1   135
c_b   2   984
```

Is there a way to do this that is feasible for ~50 clusters?

Comment: You should probably do this with three tables instead of two.  Clusters, Users, and UserClusters.

Comment: But "1" and "2" are in both clusters, so I have no idea why you are choose those particular rows.

Answer (score 0):

seems you need  union

```
select 'c_a' cluster, b.c_a,  a.number
from table_b
inner join table_a on a.id = b.c_a and b.user = 1 
union all
select 'c_b' , b.c_b, a.numbrer 
from table_b
inner join table_a on a.id = b.c_ab and b.user = 1
```